# Geting specific key from JSON File

Tags: python, json

I'm making a project in Python that requires a user's login info. I'm using a `UserInfo.json` to read the `username` and `password` values.

this is my JSON:

```json
{
  "username": "MyUsername",
  "password": "MyPassword"
}
```

and im currently using this block:

```py
def readJson(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f)
    return data


userData = readJson('UserInfo.json')
print(userData['username'])
```

When I try to read the `username` key from the JSON. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or byte array, not TextIOWrapper
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be `data = json.load(f)`.`json.loads` would load a string as a json.

Comment: `data = json.loads(f.read())`

Comment: I'm sorry it was my dumb mistake. I didn't save the file before running it so it was returning the full JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def readJson(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    return data


userData = readJson('UserInfo.json')
print(userData['username'])
```

using `f.read()` will give you the string of contents instead of a file object.

Answer (score 0):

Just use load instead of loads.

```
def readJson(filename):
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f)
return data


userData = readJson('UserInfo.json')
print(userData['username'])
```

The reason is

- json.load() method (without “s” in “load”) used to read JSON encoded
  data from a file and convert it into Python dictionary.
- json.loads() method, which is used for parse valid JSON String into
  Python dictionary.

Here is the [link](https://pynative.com/python-json-load-and-loads-to-parse-json/) that you can refer

Answer (score -1):

I have found the issue.

I just didn't save the file before running so it was returning the full JSON. the current block works well.

Comment: even if the file is saved properly it still wont work -- see my answer

Comment: Yest thats what i am using now.